# Unsubscribe observer in Async grpc stub - Java / Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, grpc, grpc-java

I have an async stub in which I added an observer:

```
            val obs =  object: StreamObserver<Hallo> {

                override fun onNext(value: Hallo) {

                    streamSuccess(value)
                }

                override fun onError(t: Throwable?) {

                    nonSuccess(t?.message ?: "Unknow error")
                }

                override fun onCompleted() {

                    Log.d("Info", "completed")
                    completed()
                }
            }
```

I would like a to be able to remove this observer from the async stub, so I can cancel the streaming in the client side.

As says in the github issue: https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java/issues/3095

I tried keeping a local variable of the observer, so the client can do later on:

```
observer?.onError(Status.CANCELLED.cause)
```

That didn't work.

Also I tried to create my own class from the abstract class: `ClientCallStreamObserver`

```
class CancellableStreamObserver<TResponse>(val next:(value:TResponse)->Unit, val onError:(t:Throwable)-> Unit, val onCompleted:(()->Unit), val onCanceledHandler: (()->Unit)? = null) : ClientCallStreamObserver<TResponse>() {
        override fun isReady(): Boolean {
            return  true
        }

        override fun setOnReadyHandler(onReadyHandler: Runnable?) {
            //TODO("not implemented") //To change body of created functions use File | Settings | File Templates.
        }

        override fun disableAutoInboundFlowControl() {
            //TODO("not implemented") //To change body of created functions use File | Settings | File Templates.
        }

        override fun cancel(message: String?, cause: Throwable?) {

            //TODO("not implemented") //To change body of created functions use File | Settings | File Templates.
        }

        override fun request(count: Int) {
            //TODO("not implemented") //To change body of created functions use File | Settings | File Templates.
        }

        override fun setMessageCompression(enable: Boolean) {
            //TODO("not implemented") //To change body of created functions use File | Settings | File Templates.
        }

        override fun onNext(value: TResponse) {
            next(value)
        }

        override fun onError(t: Throwable) {
            if (t is StatusException) {
                if (t.status.code == Status.Code.CANCELLED) {
                    onCanceledHandler?.let {
                        it()
                    }
                }
            }
            if (t is StatusRuntimeException) {
                if (t.status.code == Status.Code.CANCELLED) {
                    onCanceledHandler?.let {
                        it()
                    }
                }
            }
            this.onError(t)
        }

        override fun onCompleted() {
            onCompleted()
        }
    }
```

So later on I can call:

```
        observer?.cancel("Cancelled for the user",Status.CANCELLED.cause)
```

That didn't work either.

The way I know it didn't work, it's because if the user adds again a new observer, I get duplicated responses, as if the old observer is still alive.

I know I can shutdown the channel with `channel.shutdownNow()`. But I think it's too aggressive.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the referenced https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java/issues/3095:

> for async you can use ClientCallStreamObserver.cancel() by casting the *returned* StreamObserver to ClientCallStreamObserver or implementing having your passed-in StreamObserver implement ClientResponseObserver.

(emphasis added)

grpc-java will implement the appropriate methods, not your instance. So the pattern would be:

```
stub.foo(req, object: ClientResponseObserver<Hallo> {
    override fun beforeStart(respObs: ClientCallStreamObserver<Hallo>) {
        // save respObs for later
    }
    override fun onNext(value: Hallo) {
        streamSuccess(value)
    }
    override fun onError(t: Throwable?) {
        nonSuccess(t?.message ?: "Unknow error")
    }
    override fun onCompleted() {
        Log.d("Info", "completed")
        completed()
    }
});

// -or- (for streaming calls only)

val obs = ...;
val respObs = stub.foo(obs) as (ClientCallStreamObserver<Hallo>);
respObs.onNext(req);
// save respObs for later
```

Note that the `respObs` in both cases would be identical. Using `ClientResponseObserver` would mainly be for when there is streaming and want to cancel within the response observer to avoid threading races.

Comment: Neat! It works perfectly. I guess I wasn't following the wrong hint :)
Just one thing, I think: val respObs = (ClientCallStreamObserver<Hallo>) stub.foo(req, obs); should be: val respObs =  stub.foo(req, obs) as (ClientCallStreamObserver<Hallo>)

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Fixed. I don't know Kotlin :-)

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong but I discovered the second option it doesn't work. stub.foo(req,obs) doesn't return anything, so Kotlin silently complains in the log that it can't convert Unit ( which is like void in Kotlin ) to (ClientCallStreamObserver<Hallo>). I had to do the first way but adding the request: object: ClientResponseObserver<Any, Hallo> { . It may be not the best way but it seems to be working.

Comment: @xarly, ah, you are right. That second one is a solution, but only for streaming RPCs. I updated the answer to mention that.

Comment: Mmm I don't think so that's right (at least in my particular case ). I'm using a streaming rpc and stub.foo(req, obs) doesn't return anything. Also I can't do stub.foo(obs), the only method generated has two parameters; The request and the observer.

Comment: The second case version is only for the stub methods that return a stream observer (client-streaming and bidi streaming). If the request is passed as an argument to the stub then you need to use ClientResponseObserver.